# Load Polygon with variable path into GOOGLE MAP API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

When I initialize my map, I would like to generate a polygon using as path the value stored into an input html field.

```
    polytest = document.getElementById('acf-field_5e59146d57037').value;
    addPolygon(polytest);
function addPolygon(polytest){
    polytototo = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: polytest,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        editable: true,
    });
    polytototo.setMap(map);
}
```

when I copy/past my data from the input field id called `'acf-field_5e59146d57037'` that is what I get `{lat: 66.064964, lng: 112.872635}, {lat: 42.249039, lng: 87.560135}, {lat: 55.940113, lng: 60.841385}`

When I put this data inside `path: [{lat: 66.064964, lng: 112.872635}, {lat: 42.249039, lng: 87.560135}, {lat: 55.940113, lng: 60.841385}]`, it works....

How can I make it works with the variable `polytest` (as in the main code above) ?

EDIT: maybe the the method to send data into the html input field can be important. Actually datas of an existing draw polygon are send into the html, like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        polypoint = polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6).split(",");
        if (i === 0) { prefix_coord = '{'; } else { prefix_coord = ', {'; }
      document.getElementById('acf-field_5e59146d57037').value += prefix_coord + 'lat: ' + polypoint[0] + ', lng: ' + polypoint[1] + '}';

    }

  });
```

Comment: Try `path: JSON.parse(\`[${polytest}]\`)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code as is, I get javascript errors:

- `InvalidValueError: not an Array`

The problem is that: `"{lat: 66.064964, lng: 112.872635}, {lat: 42.249039, lng: 87.560135}, {lat: 55.940113, lng: 60.841385}"` is not an array, it is a string.

If you add "[]" around it, put quotes around property names (run it through [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)),  and call `JSON.parse` on it, it will be an array:

```
<input id='acf-field_5e59146d57037' value="[{lat: 66.064964, lng: 112.872635}, {lat: 42.249039, lng: 87.560135}, {lat: 55.940113, lng: 60.841385}]" />
```

Use that array for the Polygon's path.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4e6katmp/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
var map;
var bounds;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 24.886,
      lng: -70.268
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  polytest = document.getElementById('acf-field_5e59146d57037').value;
  console.log(polytest);
  polytest =JSON.parse(polytest);
  for (var i=0; i<polytest.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(polytest[i])
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  addPolygon(polytest);
}

function addPolygon(polytest) {
  polytototo = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: polytest,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    editable: true,
  });
  polytototo.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input size="100" id='acf-field_5e59146d57037' value='[{"lat": 66.064964, "lng": 112.872635}, {"lat": 42.249039, "lng": 87.560135}, {"lat": 55.940113, "lng": 60.841385}]' />
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```